# Editions of IUPAC Green Book

Tags: books

Why does the URL https://www.iupac.org/cms/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Green-Book-PDF-Version-2011.pdf (ending in **2011**) contain the Green Book labelled **2007**, and reprinted in **2008**? Does a 2011 edition exist and they just uploaded the wrong file?

Same goes for the URL http://media.iupac.org/publications/books/gbook/IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-22apr2011.pdf (containing the exact same file).

And there is the version https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf with different water mark, one page more, and the front matter in a different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantities,_Units_and_Symbols_in_Physical_Chemistry) reads:

> The third edition of the Green Book (ISBN 978-0-85404-433-7) was first published by IUPAC in 2007. A second printing of the third edition was released in 2008; this printing made several minor revisions to the 2007 text. A third printing of the third edition was released in 2011. The text of the third printing is identical to that of the second printing.

So yes, maybe they uploaded the wrong file. But the content of 2011 and 2008 should be 100% identical.